# Should my question be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1394317/213131) about network shares becoming inaccessible on my Windows computer. It was closed as a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/q/1392563/213131) question.

I'm not convinced mine should be closed as a duplicate of the other:

- My question explains the symptoms *in detail* including screen shots and actual error messages. The other simply states, *"I'm no longer able to access files via SMB shares."*
- Mine is focused on solving the problem with the shares. The other poster isn't, saying, *"I restored my system to a previous restore point and the issue appears to be resolved..."*
- The other question appears more interested in what one should do when updates break your computer, and simply gives this situation as an *example*. Specifically the other Q asks, *"...In general what should I do in these situations?"* and, *"Do I just need to disable automatic updates?"*

For the sake of argument, supposing we feel my question is indeed a duplicate, I offer that while the other was in fact asked first, my question is of better quality and the closure should be the other way around (though for the reasons listed above I wouldn't want that because I don't think they're asking the same thing in the first place).

**Should my question be closed as a duplicate?**

Answer (score -1):

> My question explains the symptoms in detail including screen shots and actual error messages. The other simply states, "I'm no longer able to access files via SMB shares."

While your question contains more details, at the end of the day, you both at the same problem with the same patch.  You also both accepted pratically the same answer, with the only difference being, that the problem was resovled by the time you submitted your answer.

> Mine is focused on solving the problem with the shares. The other poster isn't, saying, "I restored my system to a previous restore point and the issue appears to be resolved..."

While the author might have restored their system, using a restore point when the patch in question was not installed, at the end of the day their problem was caused by the same patch.  `KB4480970` and `KB4480960` were both known to cause the problem both questions describe.

> The other question appears more interested in what one should do when updates break your computer, and simply gives this situation as an example. Specifically the other Q asks, "...In general what should I do in these situations?" and, "Do I just need to disable automatic updates?"

The other question also accepted an answer, that indicate the problem was caused by the same patch, it is important to link releated issues.

> For the sake of argument, supposing we feel my question is indeed a
>   duplicate, I offer that while the other was in fact asked first, my
>   question is of better quality and the closure should be the other way
>   around (though for the reasons listed above I wouldn't want that
>   because I don't think they're asking the same thing in the first
>   place).

I personally flagged your question, as a duplicate, due to the fact both questions had the exact same answer.  It is important to link releated issues together.

> Should my question be closed as a duplicate?

Considering I issued the first duplicate vote, I certainly feel the question is a duplicate, but I am more interested in answers not being duplicated accross multiple different questions, then worrying about any specific outcome.  *So if the two questions can be linked, that would be an acceptable solution, allowing a single question that can be used to close questions that describe the same problem.*

Comment: I understanding your reasoning, though I don't fully agree that even the answers support this conclusion. But that aside, could you please also expand your answer to explain why you feel the less clear, less specific question should be the target?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator - It's simply based on the fact, the clarity of the original question, was not an issue for me.  Nor does it appear to be an issue for yourself since you also answered it.

Comment: In other words, you don't find that my post asks the question significantly more clearly. I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator - I have no opinion on that particular point.  **I am extremely careful of the words I use, if I had an opinion, I would state it.**.  Only what I have stated in my answe, using the words I have used, is my what I believe.  Dont make any other conclusions, because, they won’t be accurate.